# Should I use for loop? OR apply?

Tags: r

this is my first post.

I have this dataframe of the Nhl draft. 
What I would like to do is to use some sort of recursive function to create 10 objects.

So, I want to create these 10 objects by subsetting the Nhl dataframe by Year. 
Here are the first 6 rows of the data set (nhl_draft)

```
Year Overall                  Team
1 2000       1    New York Islanders
2 2000       2     Atlanta Thrashers
3 2000       3        Minnesota Wild
4 2000       4 Columbus Blue Jackets
5 2000       5    New York Islanders
6 2000       6   Nashville Predators
            Player    PS
1    Rick DiPietro  49.3
2     Dany Heatley  95.2
3   Marian Gaborik 103.6
4 Rostislav Klesla  34.5
5     Raffi Torres  28.4
6   Scott Hartnell  74.5
```

I want to create 10 objects by subsetting out the Years, 2000 ~ 2009.
I tried,

```
for (i in 2000:2009) {
  nhl_draft.i <- subset(nhl_draft, Year == "i")
}
```

BUT this doesn't do anything. What's the problem with this for-loop? Can you suggest any other ways?

Please tell me if this is confusing after all, this is my first post......

Comment: How about use `split` to separate all the data?  `nhl_list <- split(nhl_draft, f = nhl_draft$Year)`

Comment: `L <- split(nhl_draft, nhl_draft$Year)` makes a list of dataframes, for each `$Year` a dataframe. (as @ycw said)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code may fix your error.

```
# Create an empty list
nhl_list <- list()

for (i in 2000:2009) {
  # Subset the data frame based on Year
  nhl_draft_temp <- subset(nhl_draft, Year == i)
  # Assign the subset to the list
  nhl_list[[as.character(i)]] <- nhl_draft_temp
}
```

But you can consider `split`, which is more concise.

```
nhl_list <- split(nhl_draft, f = nhl_draft$Year)
```

Comment: How do i convert nhl_list into a data frame?

Comment: Are you talking about access one of the subset in `nhl_list`? You can access each data frame by calling the name of the data frame. In this case, the name is `Year`. For example, `nhl_list[["2000"]]` is the subset from `2000`. Please note that use double bracket and enclose the number of year in "".