# Faster way to do repetitive subsetting of a list

Tags: r, function, loops, repeat

This is my second question here. This is related to my first question here: [Should I use for loop? OR apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595502/should-i-use-for-loop-or-apply)

I'm analyzing NHL draft data. Looking at answers to the first question,
I learned to use split:

```
canucks_year <- split(canucks, canucks$Year)
```

BUT I want to make new objects, such as canucks_2000, canucks_2001 that only contain data frame of the respective years. So, I coded:

```
canucks_2000 <- canucks_year[["2000"]]
canucks_2001 <- canucks_year[["2001"]]
canucks_2002 <- canucks_year[["2002"]]
canucks_2003 <- canucks_year[["2003"]]
```

Is there any magic way to use some function in R to automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function called `list2env`, this allows you to put all elements of your list into a specified environment.

```
names(canucks_year) = paste0('canucks_', names(canucks_year))
list2env(canucks_year, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I first renamed the elements of your list from 2000, 2001, 2002,... to canucks_2000, canucks_2001, canucks_2002,... then used `list2env` to put all elements into the global environment.

Comment: Ok I get the first line. I don't understand the second line. Specifically, what is a global environment and why did you move the elements there? Thanks!

Comment: @JasonJoonWooBaik The global environment is the main environment where all your variables, functions and datasets are sitting in R. Basically, whenever you create a new variable like `variable = something` (not inside a function), you are placing it in your global environment. `list2env` is basically just taking all elements of your list and doing `canucks_2000 = canucks_year[["2000"]]` _for each element_.